# Define Tkinter Widgets in Function but Reference it Elsewhere

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to create a second button that appears when you click the first button. Afterwards, when you click the first button, the second button's attributes should change (in this case, the text in the second button changes). Unfortunately, the code below does not work.

```
import tkinter as tk
root=tk.Tk()

def onclick():
    if onclick.has_been_called == False:
        success2 = tk.Button(root, text="something").pack(padx=0, pady=5)
        onclick.has_been_called = True
    else:
        success2.config(text = "something else")

onclick.has_been_called = False
button = tk.Button(root, text="Create Simulation Files", command=onclick).pack(padx=0, pady=15)
```

The error is in the "else" statement, and it states
`UnboundLocalError: local variable 'success2' referenced before assignment`. Because the onclick() function, when activated the second time, cannot access the 'success2' variable established the first time the function was run, it cannot modify/config it.

I'm trying to figure out how to generally define tkinter widgets within a function while being able to access them outside of that specific function. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you very much.

Comment: The error is telling you precisely what is wrong. Did you intend for `success2` to be global?

Comment: @Bryan Oakley - I'm so sorry! I copied the wrong error message. I just put the correct error message. It's an unbound local error.

Comment: `success2` is only defined if the `if` statement is triggered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few things to keep in mind here, your button will only be created if the `if` statement is executed, which means it cannot be accessed or used in `else` initially. For that you have to create the button outside the `if`. But doing this, will create new button each time the function is run, which is inefficient and creates more unused(or unseen) buttons. So you will have to define the button outside the function and then change its text and position it, inside the function, like:

```
def onclick():
    success2.config(text="something") # Change the text when function is called
    if not onclick.has_been_called: # if onclick.has_been_called == False:
        success2.pack(padx=0, pady=5) # Position it 
        success2.config(text="something")
        onclick.has_been_called = True
    else:
        success2.config(text="something else")

onclick.has_been_called = False
button = tk.Button(root, text="Create Simulation Files", command=onclick).pack(padx=0, pady=15)
success2 = tk.Button(root) # Define the button outside the func
```

Keep in mind not to to tell `x = Button.pack()` as you are assigning `None` to `x`, which will give errors later, when you reuse the button.

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked perfectly. I'm guessing that .pack() is like a show function, where before you actually explicitly define .pack() the success2 button appears "invisible"? Either way, this is very clever and really helped me as a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be a "success2"(as mentioned in your error message) attribute in your given code.
Is it possible that the problem is caused by a typo?

Comment: This is better as a comment, rather than answer.

Comment: Yep! Sorry, I changed a few of the variables in my Stack OverFlow question to make it easier to understand, and I wasn't careful. Fixed - but there's still a problem in the original code (where both variables are "success2").

Answer (score 0):

`success2` is local variable which is destroyed when it exits `onclick` - and when you run `onclick` againt then `success2` doesn't exist so it can't get `success2.config()` and you get your error.

In your situation you have to use `global` to inform function that it has to assign button to external/global variable `success2` instead of creating local one.

But there is other common mistake.

If you run

```
success2 = tk.Button(...).pack()
```

then you assing `None` to `success2` because `pack()`/`grid()`/`place()` returns `None.

If you want to use `success2` later then you have to do it in two steps

```
success2 = tk.Button(...)
success2.pack()
```

If you don't want to use `success2` later then you could skip this variable

```
tk.Button(...).pack()
```

---

```
import tkinter as tk

# --- functions ---

def onclick():
    global success2
    
    if onclick.has_been_called == False:
        success2 = tk.Button(root, text="something")
        success2.pack(padx=0, pady=5)
        onclick.has_been_called = True
    else:
        success2.config(text = "something else")

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

onclick.has_been_called = False

button = tk.Button(root, text="Create Simulation Files", command=onclick)
button.pack(padx=0, pady=15)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The main reason I did not use `global` in my solution was that its discouraged. Any other solutions?

Comment: other solution is to put all in class and use `self.success2` - it will be simpler to use `global`

Comment: eventually create button at start (outside function) - and then it will be global - and later only use `pack()` to show it. Like in @CoolCloud answer

Comment: This also worked perfectly! Thank you so much for explaining pack() and how it works. I did go with Cool Cloud's solution because I've heard about global variables not being used generally, but I think your solution works great as well and I wanted to thank you for your contribution.

Comment: I wanted to ask - is there a way to "unpack" or "hide" elements from Tkinter windows without completely removing them?

Comment: `pack_forget()`, `grid_forget()`, `place_forget()`. Probably even `forget()` should do it. But if you use `pack_forget()` on element between other elements and later use `pack()` then it put it at the end - not in previous place.